# Javascript Motion Detection

Tags: javascript, html, css, camera, motion-detection

I am looking for a plugin/library for Javascript that can detect motion in a video stream from a web camera.

It needs to have some sort of callback like:

```
Motion.onMotion(function(){
   // Do Something Here
});
```

That is literally all I need it to do.

Answer (score -1):

There's a library called [Reallygood](http://reallygood.co.il/plugins/motion/) for javascript motion detection. Please check it.
Motion can be detected using this code, which is probably like what you're looking for:

```
$('#one').on('motion', function(){
        console.log('touched one');
    });
```

Here's the [github](https://github.com/ReallyGood/js-motion-detection).

Comment: That's for changing elements on a page. I'm looking for something that detects motion in a video stream. Directly from the web camera. I was looking at "Gest.js" but it only calls back when it detects motion in a specific direction.

Comment: Sorry, about that, I didn't notice you were looking for a video stream.